# WCF web service unable to use GZipMessageEncoding with HTTPS from wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, gzip

Before implementing gzip, my client & server solution works fine with wsHttpBinding, with kerberos(SPN) and HTTPS. After find out that the data being transmitted is huge, I decided to use IIS compression. But I learnt that IIS will only compress response, not request from client. So, had decided to give it a try for gzip message encoding.

I had implemented gzip compression for wcf web service by referring to Microsoft web site. Everything works fine if I run under NTLM with NO HTTPS. But I could not run it user Kerberos and HTTPS.

Below is my C# coding from GZipCompressionCustomBinding inherit from CustomBinding.

```
public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
{
    GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement gzipElement;
    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncodingBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    gzipElement = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(textMessageEncodingBindingElement);

    // Copy from existing HTTPS setting from wsHttpBinding.
    WSHttpBinding wSHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding("RMSBinding_HTTPS");
    BindingElementCollection wSHttpBindingElementCollection = wSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements();

    HttpsTransportBindingElement transportElement = wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Remove<HttpsTransportBindingElement>();
    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textElement = wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Remove<TextMessageEncodingBindingElement>();

    wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Add(gzipElement);
    wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Add(transportElement);

    return wSHttpBindingElementCollection;        
}
```

Reason I do the above coding to copy from wsHttpBinding is that, I need most of the security configuration similar to wsHttpBinding with security model is TransportWithMessageCredential and clientCredentialType is Windows.

Below is my web.config from wcf web service and app.config from client app.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding
  name="RMSBinding_HTTPS"
  closeTimeout="00:10:00"
  openTimeout="00:10:00"
  receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
  sendTimeout="00:10:00"
  bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
  transactionFlow="false"
  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646"
  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
  messageEncoding="Text"
  textEncoding="utf-8"
  useDefaultWebProxy="true"
  allowCookies="true">

  <readerQuotas
    maxDepth="2147483646"
    maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
    maxArrayLength="2147483646"
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483646"
    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />

  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <transport
      clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    <message
      clientCredentialType="Windows"
      negotiateServiceCredential="true"
      establishSecurityContext="false" />
  </security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

I hit this error when browse to my web service in IE:

> The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
>   Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress

In Stack Trace, I saw this line:
CustomBindingElements\GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement.cs    Line:  166

I further look into the coding mentioned above:

```
    public override IChannelListener<TChannel> BuildChannelListener<TChannel>(BindingContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        context.BindingParameters.Add(this);
        return context.BuildInnerChannelListener<TChannel>();
    }
```

I went into debugging this line and realize that, the web service address in context.ListenUriBaseAddress is actually http://xxxx.svc
I have no clue that why is this in http even I just run web service in IE, not even run in client application.

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy?

Comment: As far as I know, I am not using any. I can't even run it on my local dev machine which run casini. I then try in server with proper IIS deployment, still can't.